# Simple Python AES decryption for longer ciphertexts

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, pycrypto

I am not an expert in AES and moreover I have to deliver the deciphering function to a very limited Python 2 environment.

I have a 32-byte **key** and a 16-byte initialisation **vector** along with a 64-byte test cipher **message** - all of type `str`. AES operates in a cipher-block chaining mode.

With `pycrypto` it all works and I get a 64-symbol decrypted message of type `unicode`.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, vector)
decryption = cipher.decrypt(message).decode()
print(decryption)
```

Unfortunately the `pycrypto` itself is not supported in the final environment as I believe it has some fancy compiled dependencies for AES.
There is a purely Python alternative called `pyaes`:

```
import pyaes

cipher = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCBC(key, vector)
decryption = cipher.decrypt(message[0:16]).decode()
print(decryption)
```

Notice that I sliced the first 16 bytes and got the first 16 symbols of the decrypted message (of type `unicode`) correctly.

However, once I try the full message I get
`ValueError: ciphertext block must be 16 bytes`.

Even if I slice `message[16:32]`, I get 
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`.

So how to use the `pyaes` and decrypt longer ciphertexts in my case?

---

The secret plaintext looks like this

```
{"valueInt":123, "valueFloat":1.23, "valueString":"123"}
```

with trailing (padded) spaces.

Comment: The problem is not (directly) related to pyaes, which can successfully encrypt and decrypt any sequence of **bytes**, but an incorrect bytes to unicode conversion. I'm surprised that you tag the question python-2.7 and say that you *get a 64-symbol decrypted message of type **unicode**.* from `cipher.decrypt(message)`. But I cannot say more without a [mcve]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibility 1. The case of the message[16:32] is that the first part of your unencrypted text could have multibyte characters, so after taking 16 bytes, 1+ byte is leaking to the second part of your original/unencrypted string. Though this is only if you are using multibyte characters.

If you are also encrypting them, you could try converting the text to binary first if your encoding is utf8:

```
cipher.encrypt(mystring.encode('utf8'))
```

and in reverse

```
cipher.decrypt(mystring.decode('utf8'))
```

Possiblity 2. If you are decrypting with the same AESModeOfOperationCFB you should try with a new instance for decryption. The following code fails to decrypt the correct text which contains non valid ascii bytes.

```
cipher = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCBC(key, vector)
encrypted = cipher.decrypt('Hello world')
print(encrypted)
# ?Eg?m??K?(|
decrypted = cipher.decrypt(encrypted)
print(decrypted)
# ?XL=?-QE??Y?=k
```

But if you do this way:

```
encrypter = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCBC(key, vector)
encrypted = cipher.encrypt('Hello world !!!!')
print(encrypted)
# ?Eg?m??K?(|
decrypter = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCBC(key, vector)
decrypted = decrypter.decrypt(encrypted)
# Hello world !!!!
```

If you are encrypting 2 blocks with same instance and then concatenate them, you need a new instance which decrypt 2 new blocks. Or encrypt/decrypt each block with a new instance each.